# Parsing String to Time makes 01:00:00

Tags: java, parsing, time

When I do the following:

```
String start = request.getParameter("startp");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");  
long ms=0;
try {
    ms = sdf.parse(start).getTime();
} catch (ParseException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
Time ts = new Time(ms);
```

it is inserted with this value 01:00:00 witch is not the correct one (entered by user).

I don't understand the error here. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, it's not [casting](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html), it's [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) (I have updated the title and the tags accordingly). Second, as per the `SimpleDateFormat` [API document](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) two-digit 24h-hours are to be represented by `HH`, not by `hh`.

To nail the root cause better down, you'll have to update your question to include the *actual* values of `start`, `ms` and `ts`. Print them using `System.out.println()` or a logger. If all looks fine, then the problem is in the SQL or the DB table model, you need to ensure that you're setting it using [`PreparedStatement#setTime()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTime%28int,%20java.sql.Time%29) and that the DB table column type is of at least `TIME` type.